# CocoaPods: Unable to install Gmail-API PodFile

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods, gmail-api

I'm following Google's quick start guide for Gmail-API which can be found
[here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/ios?ver=objc) and I'm running into an issue installing the podfile. In the podfile's text I put exactly what it said, which is this.

`platform :ios, '7.0'
target 'QuickstartApp' do
    pod 'GoogleAPIClientForREST/Gmail', '~> 1.0.3'
    pod 'GTMOAuth2', '~> 1.1.2'
end`

But for some reason in CocoaPods when I click the install button I get this error.

> [!] Unable to find a specification for `'GoogleAPIClientForREST/Gmail (~> 1.0.3)`'

The ' are actually `

How do I fix this? The name of the xcode project is called "QuickstartApp".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to update pod for "Update outdated project dependencies and create new Podfile.lock"

```
pod update && pod install
```

Comment: Okay, I'll try that.

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks.